# Handling network and socket connection using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, internet-connection, frp

I am learning reactive programming and specifically ReactiveCocoa right now and I am unsure how to handle network connection and socket connection.

**The Application:**
The application waits for a network connection then logs in by obtaining a token from a restful backend and then connects to a socket using this token.

I solved this by chaining three signals which essentially causes the application to perform one task after another:
*when theres internet -> get token -> when there's a token -> connect socket*
Now if I lose my network connection and regain it at some point this process will start from the beginning and reconnect the socket.

**The Problem**
What if the socket disconnects even though the network connection remains steady (which can happen quite often)? The chain would only restart if the network connection is lost and gained again. So the socket should try to connect again when it disconnects but only if there's a network connection.

How do I implement these dependencies using ReactiveCocoa or reactive programming in general?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this would be implemented /specifically/ in Reactive Cocoa, but my off-the cuff solution is to join the first and last cell:

- When there's internet and no socket: get token -> connect

That way, when the 'internet is there' condition changes to true, the process starts, and also, when the 'socket exists' condition changes to false, the process starts.

For example, in something like Sodium(Java) you might use a cell like this:

```
Cell< Boolean > hasInternet;
Cell< Socket > socket;

Cell< Boolean > shouldGetToken = Cell.lift( 
    (hi, s) -> hi && socket == null, hasInternet, socket );
```